# Style an element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to use jQuery to style a tooltip element.

```js
$('.tooltip').css({
  background:'#96c11f',
  padding:'20px',
  width:'100%',
  display:'block',
  text-align:'center',
  color:'white',
  font-size:'1.4em',
  margin-bottom:'40px'
});
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hello!</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4okqkys2/

Can someone explain why it isn't styling as expected?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For properties with multiple words you should use Camel case or write key inside quotes so for example `font-size` should be `'font-size'`

```js
$('.tooltip').css({
  background: '#96c11f',
  padding: '20px',
  width: '100%',
  display: 'block',
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: 'white',
  fontSize: '1.4em',
  marginBottom: '40px'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip">Hello!</div>
```